# If and Else statement Doesn't work with API?

Tags: javascript, html, api

i have got this Code that displays bitcoin Price and base and other things, but i want to make it so that before the data arrives(i made a setInterval to 3 seconds) it displays "Waiting for Data to Arrive..."
and after it arrives it says "Data Arrived!" (P.S: I'm Using Axios library)
here is my HTML and JS
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JSON Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="num"></h1>
    <h1 id="num1"></h1>
    <h1 id="num2"></h1>
    <h1 id="num3"></h1>
    <h1 id="num4"></h1>
    <h1 id="num5"></h1>
    <script src="zoom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and JS

```
const num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
const num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
const num3 = document.getElementById("num3");
const num4 = document.getElementById("num4");
const num5 = document.getElementById("num5");
const num = document.getElementById("num");
if(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5.innerText.length > 0) {
    num.innerText = `Data Arrived!`
} else {
    num.innerText = `Waiting for Data to Arrive...`
}
setInterval(() => {
    const bitcoin = axios.get('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd')
    .then(res => {
        num1.innerText = `${"Current Base"}, ${res.data.ticker.base}` 
        num2.innerText = `${"Current Currency"}, ${res.data.ticker.target}`
        num3.innerText = `${"Current Bitcoin Price"}, ${res.data.ticker.price}` 
        num4.innerText = `${"Current Volume"}, ${res.data.ticker.volume}` 
        num5.innerText = `${"Current Change"}, ${res.data.ticker.change}`
}) 
    .catch(err => {
        num1.innerHTML = `<strong>ERROR: Nothing found!<strong>`
        num2.style.opacity = 0;
        num3.style.opacity = 0;
        num4.style.opacity = 0;
        num5.style.opacity = 0;
    })
}, 5000);
```

this is the method i tried, or is there something wrong with the syntax of my If and Else statement?

```
if(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5.innerText.length > 0) {
    num.innerText = `Data Arrived!`
} else {
    num.innerText = `Waiting for Data to Arrive...`
}
```

Comment: replace all your commas with `&&`

Comment: `if (num1 && num2 &&...)`

Comment: oh, wait, are you trying to check ALL of their `innerText.length` properties?

Comment: @TKoL not sure checking the length makes sense because `num1`, `num2`, etc are HTML elements. Unless it's to check the content?

Comment: @VLAZ I got the impression, after my first two comments, that he meant to do `num1.innerText.length > 0 && num2.innerText.length ...`

Comment: i was trying to check all the h1s such as num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 to check if all of their innertext.length was 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems.

## The comma operator doesn't do what you think

The comma operator returns whatever is on the right hand side of it. `if (a,b)` means the same as `if (b)`.

If you want to test `num1.innerText.length > 0` AND the same for `num2` and so on then you have to test all of their lengths, and use the `&&` operator instead of the `,` operator.

Although you can do a shortcut where you write a function that does the test on each thing in an array and then test if all of them are OK.

```
if (![num1, num2, num3, num4, num5].some(
    element => element.innerText.length === 0
)) {
```

## `if` statements don't apply retroactively

You test your condition at the start of the program.

**Then** you start running your interval

**Later** the interval changes the values so the `if` statement would past

… but you aren't running the `if` statement again.

The changes you are making to the element aren't going to travel back in time to when you performed the `if` test.

You need to do that test after you change the elements.

**However** that is pointless. You set all the values at once, and you know when you set them.

You can just hard code  `Waiting for Data to Arrive…` into the HTML, and then replace it with `Data Arrived` at the same time as you replace the `innerText` of the other elements.

Comment: @Jamiec — Yes. I haven't used `some` enough to remember it exists.

Comment: Thanks! for this solution i totally forgot about the AND && operator and the position of my  if and else